# How to render a UIView with transparent background on an SCNPlane in ARKit?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, scenekit, arkit

My UIView has a `UIColor.clear` background. I am instantiating the View Controller from a storyboard.

When I set `SCNPlane` geometry's diffuse contents to the viewcontroller's view, the Transparent background appears solid white on the plane.
here is how I set it

```
let material = SCNMaterial()
material.diffuse.contents = viewController.view
planeGeometry.materials = [material]
```

I can see the view, just the background is not transparent.

I saw suggestion on other Stack overflow posts where they suggested to try this

```
material.diffuse.contents = viewController.view.layer
```

This works and the the plane renders the transparencies, but then the view is not interactive anymore.

Is there a way that I can retain the interactivity and the transparency when the view is rendered on the plane?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try setting your view's [isOpaque](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622622-isopaque) property to `false`:

```
let material = SCNMaterial()
viewController.view.isOpaque = false
material.diffuse.contents = viewController.view
planeGeometry.materials = [material]
```