# ARKit snapshot only rendered content

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

Fellows,
I'm using ARSCNView, I need to capture camera's content and rendered (virtual) content into separate UIImages.

To capture camera's content I'm using ARFrame.capturedImage.

The question is how can I capture virtual content with transparent background?

Comment: Does this answer your questions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56264731/how-to-render-a-uiview-with-transparent-background-on-an-scnplane-in-arkit?

Comment: @swiftlearneer no it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

Solution found!
I was able to remove real content by setting scene background content and snapshot view after that

```
arView.isOpaque = false
arView.scene.background.contents = .clear
```